# Is there a feature pack for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2008 offered a feature pack with which one could create code-frameworks for office-style applications:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6922

Am I allowed to use this with my Visual Studio 2013 license? Or can I find a feature pack (or code-snippet) for Visual Studio 2013 which offers that functionality (Visual C++, MFC)?

Comment: AFAIK those classes (`CMFC..`) have been distributed as part of MFC since VS2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The features of the Feature Pack were rolled into VS proper with VS 2008 SP1. They've been shipped as part of the base VS distribution ever since (at least in the versions that include MFC at all). You can now use all the ribbon bars, dockable windows, etc., without adding anything to VS as it comes out of the box.