# Custom MFC listbox or menu control for Metro Look

Tags: c++, mfc, microsoft-metro, controls, clistbox

We are looking for alternatives to replicate the look of the list/menu control that appears in the "Excel Options" settings, left hand edge. This is not a standard MFC control provided by Visual Studio. It has two enhancements to a standard list box control that are make it look very "nice" as a "selection control", almost like a vertically oriented tab. These include:

1. responding to a hovering mouse [in Excel's case, by changing color]
2. allowing use of the equivalent to a menu separator

Thanks in advance to the community. Yes, very similar controls are readily available in CSS, but apparently not in Visual Studio for MFC/C++ development.

[image: Screenshot of Excel's Listbox implementation]

Comment: You will have to implement the rendering yourself. MFC already provides the basic infrastructure so that you can derive from a standard control and implement the drawing in the derived class. [TN014: Custom Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk2h3c6w.aspx) has all the information you need. A walkthrough style guide can be found at [Developing Custom Draw Controls in Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048.aspx).

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to show what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the link, IInspectable. thomiel, my screen grab of the Excel controls appears on the web page now.

Comment: Take a look to [BCG ContorolBar Pro](http://www.bcgsoft.com/bcgcontrolbarpro.htm) or [MFC Featured Pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861011/is-there-a-feature-pack-for-visual-studio-2013) (which is free and "reduced" version of BCG ControlBar).

Comment: This  turned out to be a lot easier than I had thought it would be. Need to override the DrawItem and MeasureItem CListBox virtual functions in your derived class. Thanks again to the commenters.

Comment: Don't see how to post the example code (class CListBoxEx) on this web site. Anyone who wants to see it can contact me directly.